# opal-rails in Rails 5 does not add fingerprinting to assets?

Tags: assets, ruby-on-rails-5, opal

I've precompiled my assets with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And run my rails app as:

```
rails s -e production
```

But my app does not request

- application-{fingerprint}.css
- application-{fingerprint}.js

Instead it request without fingerprint.

What could I missed out? Or is this a Rails5 bug. I have no issues with Rails4.

**Updated:**

I've found the problem to be caused by opal-rails.
As I've create my app with the following command

```
rails new MyApp --javascript=opal --skip-active-record
```

Starting in production does not add fingerprinting to assets with opal-rails.

It works fine with jquery-rails.

Comment: Same problem with rails5, but other staging env is ok